# Calculate Week Ending date in Oracle SQL where the week start is the previous SAT to the current FRI

Tags: sql, string, oracle, date, datetime

I have a transaction date in my table that I would like to calculate a Week Ending date for

The problem is the weeks for us go from Saturday to Friday, don't ask me why,

So for example this week, today is 10/5/2020, the week end date should be 10/09/2020

and this Saturday, 10/10/2020, would be week ending date 10/16/2020.

Anyone know how to properly achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `next_day()`:

```
select t.*,
    case when to_char(mydate, 'FMDAY') = 'FRIDAY' 
        then mydate
        else next_day(mydate, 'FRIDAY')
    end as endofweek
from mytable t
```

Note that both `to_char(..., 'DAY')` and `next_day()` are dependant on the language of your session. If your database or session are not in English language, you need to adujst the literal strings.

Comment: that looks like ti works for the most part, but the the last friday is displaying as the next week ending date not the current.  for example 9/25/2020 is coming up as week ending date 10/2/2020 instead of 9/25/2020

Comment: @TPLEE: ah yes, that's because Oracle pads the day of the week with spaces. Fixed with format modifier `'FM'`.

Comment: Works beautifully.  Thank you so much

Comment: In order to be independent from current user session NLS-Settings use `to_char(mydate, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE= American') = 'FRIDAY'`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: right, but there is no such construct for `last_day()`, as you probably know already...

Comment: Yes, it's a pity. But `to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'IW')+4, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American')` should work in any case.